# Downloading a file using C# in a MVC project?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, download

first time posting so if I make any mistakes and not follow the guidelines please correct me.

So I working on an MVC project on my own. Creating a server which will hand out files to registered users. I have some HTML experience so I tried using that to download the file but couldn't. I get the browser to try to download the file but immediately it says the file cant be found or doesn't exist. I have a feeling its because IIS is not allowing the client to access the file system. Of course its just a guess. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 as my IDE if that makes a difference. Here's the code.

```
@model MainApplication.Models.IndexViewModel
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Download";
 }

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<p class="text-success">@ViewBag.Message</p>

<div>

<ul>
    @{
        string dirPath = "\\Users\\hippiewho\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Web Application\\MainApplication\\Views\\Download";
        string dirDownPath = "..\\Download\\";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Clear();
        System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("w3logo.jpg");
    }
    @{
        List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath));
        foreach (var dir in dirs)
        {
            <li><a class="btn-block" href="@dirDownPath@dir.Substring(dir.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1)" download >@dir.Substring(dir.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1)</a></li>
        }
    }
    </ul>
</div>
```

The controller doesn't have much in it except the view() function and the ViewBag title which is download.

Comment: To get a file in MVC, you should have an action method in your controller that returns a FileResult. Also, you should probably not use absolute paths, especially not in a view. Instead, make the path relevant to the site root, or have the path defined as part of the configuration and pass that to the view as part of the model.

Comment: There are many similar questions on SO and everywhere else - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+asp.net+mvc+downloaad+file . Sample you've shown hints that you possibly did not try to find existing samples (and hence post may get downvotes for "not showing research").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mason has said, you can return from your action method a FileResult.

Example

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    string examplePathToFile = Server.MapPath("~/Downloads/Image.jpg");
    string exampleMimeType = "image/jpeg";

    return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(examplePathToFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), exampleMimeType);
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult(v=vs.118).aspx